# Nonfunctioning "for loop" for addressing each variable of class

Tags: actionscript-3, object, for-loop

I'm learning AS3 but have some antiquated background in programming (TP and Atari Basic).  On this forum I learned to use a loop such as the one below to address each variable in an object class, in order to make a clone of the object (deep or shallow) or in my case to build the text for a tooltip.  However mine doesn't work.  Here's the loop, following is an explanation, any help you can give I'd appreciate greatly!

```
var tooltipText:String;
var i:String;
for (i in bsm) {
    if (!(bsm[i] is String)) {
        if (bsm[i] != 0) {
            tooltipText = i + ": " + bsm[i];
            tooltip.extendTooltip(tooltipText, 0xFFFFFF);
        }
    }
}
```

Please forgive the horrible variable names.  'i' is a String.  'bsm' is a non-null instance of class StatMod, which begins with

```
public class StatMod extends Object {
    public static const ENCHANTMENTMODIFIER:String = "enchantmentModifier";
    public var enchantmentType:String = "None";
    public var enchantmentDescriptor:String = "None";
    public var minDamage:Number = 0;
    public var maxDamage:Number = 0;
    public var attackSpeed:Number = 0.2;
```

The intended behavior is to go through each of the variables of StatMod (I'm not showing them all and I will add more later), and if the variable is a non-zero number, make a string ("attackSpeed: 0.2" for instance) and then add that string to the tooltip.  The tooltip.extendTooltip function is working properly.

The observed behavior is basically the computer believing that there are no variables in bsm.

What can I say or do to convince the computer that there actually *are* variabels in bsm?

Comment: Instead of accessing properties from outside the object, add a method to your class that returns the `String` that the tooltip should display. You can override the method in a subclass to get different behaviour, yet take advantage of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're expecting is only the case when iterating over dynamically attached properties. For example, if you marked your class [`dynamic`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#dynamic):

```
public dynamic class StatMod { }
```

Then added some values to it at runtime:

```
bsm.test = 5;
```

Your loop will find the property `test` with the value `5`.

Some options you have to achieve what you want are:

- Extend the [`Proxy`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#nextName()) class to define what properties are iterable via `nextName` and `nextNameIndex`.
- Use [`describeType`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) to generate a list of all the public properties.

Though a simpler method is to expose a list of the properties you want to iterate over and use that in your loop instead, something like:

```
public class StatMod {
    // Existing properties etc.

    private _properties:Vector.<String>;

    public function get properties():Vector.<String> {
        if (_properties === null) {
            _properties = new <String>[
                'enchantmentType',
                'enchantmentDescription',
                'minDamage',
                'maxDamage',
                'attackSpeed'
            ];
        }

        return _properties;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < bsm.properties.length; i++) {
    var prop:String = bsm.properties[i];
    trace(prop, bsm[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'll have to look into what the underscore before the variable name means.  (If you care to explain; great, if not no problem I'm sure I can find a good explanation online.)  I actually have an improvement on this to recommend to anyone reading this in the future.  In my original code I was intending to go through all of the properties and add only those that weren't Strings.  Before this code I was doing the same thing for Strings.  I could send an argument to the "properties()" function above to tell it which set of variable names I want to deal with right now.

Comment: @DanH The underscore is just a common convention for private variables with a getter or setter :-)

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this, getters can have no arguments.  Perhaps I need multiple getters for the different set of results I desire.